# A single noun denoting a charismatic person, other than "charismatic" used as a noun?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word to denote a person who has a lot of charisma, other than "charismatic" used as a noun?

I am looking for a noun X that would fit into a sentence of the form

> John is such an X that people say he could charm birds down from the trees.

that would be similar in meaning to the sentence

> John is so charismatic that people say he could charm birds down from the trees.

Comment: Oh, is that in the rules? But there was no need for you to give me an example example. I'll add one. You didn't say what you actually want an example of, but please comment again if the example I add is unacceptable.

Comment: BTW Andy, you ran two sentences on in that comment :)

Answer (score 2):

The word "**charmer**" is defined by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/charmer) as

> A person with an attractive and engaging personality, typically one
>   who uses this to impress or manipulate others

Comment: Thanks. But formed from a transitive verb, a *charmer* is someone who knowingly uses charisma, whereas I would like a noun that simply denotes a person who possesses charisma.

Answer (score 1):

The words alluring and magnetic may be considered as alternatives to the word charismatic.

As per Merriam Webster dictionary

allure/ alluring:  to entice by charm or attraction

Magnetic :  possessing an extraordinary power or ability to attract. For example "a magnetic personality"

Comment: Thanks, but I need a noun: hence "denote" rather than "describe". I will edit the title to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestions are enchanter and bewitcher.

Enchanter (TFT)

> One that delights or fascinates.

Bewitcher (TFT)

> A person who enchants or bewitches

Bewitch (Cambridge Dictionary)

> To attract or interest someone a lot so that you have the power to influence them.